# dotless API call

Tags: dotless

Is there a way to call dotless API programmatically and get final CSS?

Something like this:

```
string lessCSS = File.ReadAllText(lessCSSfile);
string finalCSS = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(lessCSS);
```

Comment: Sounds like this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798154/how-can-i-output-errors-when-using-less-programmatically

Comment: The code you posted works fine so there is actually no point to this question..

Comment: @Tigraine, as mentioned below...the code silently throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

My CSS had a hack for IE5 and that triggered a parser exception, that's why it was not working.

Here is my test code:

```
try
{
   Ruleset ruleset = new dotless.Core.Parser.Parser().Parse(source, fileName);
   rv = ruleset.ToCSS();
}
catch (ParserException pe)
{
   Response.Write(pe.Message);
}
```